# Is it possible to parse JSON with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an external URL for a JSON file which is hosted on another domain (not mine). Is it possible to parse this information with javascript only? Here is a sample of the JSON data. I only want to get `"q"` values.

```
[{"url":"http://website.com/?q=who+is+ip+search","q":"who is ip search"},{"url":"http://website.com/?q=eclipse+visual+editor","q":"eclipse visual editor"},{"url":"http://website.com/?q=partition+recovery","q":"partition recovery"},{"url":"http://www.website.com/?q=katzenfurz","q":"katzenfurz"},{"url":"http://website.com/?q=rtfm","q":"rtfm"},{"url":"http://website.com/?q=Google+ist+Dein+Freund","q":"Google ist Dein Freund"}]
```

Comment: Check [here](http://www.json.org/js.html). Or [here](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29) Both have good explanation and samples.

Comment: I think [this site](http://www.json.org/js.html) could be what you are looking for.

Comment: Just to add some history, JSON was originally used soley in JavaScript and means JavaScript Object Notation. So yes, JSON should be parseable with JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Answer (score 6):

Browsers have native parsing methods -> `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`

There are also several libraries that add the ability to parse JSON ...

- http://www.json.org/js.html
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/json/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Eval is sometimes used directly within JavaScript - but there are often security concerns when using this method -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JavaScript_eval.28.29

Comment: Which modern browsers don't implement `JSON.parse()`? I don't think there are any...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas perhaps its all then ... i assumed some mobile browsers didnt implement it ... maybe wrongly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a built-in `JSON.parse()` function. Just pass the string to the function.

```
var obj = JSON.parse( data );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/h4XTP/

Comment: @bammab No, you have to retrieve the JSON string first... (via Ajax, of course)

Comment: ok i wasnt sure about that part that's what i need i i wll search for documentation thank you

Comment: i looked at that for jquery but i need javascript because i want to use this for a chrome extension and i dont know if you can use jquery for it

Comment: @bammab If it's for a Chrome extension, you can safely use the `XMLHttpRequest` object to fetch the JSON data...

Answer (score 0):

JSON you know is JavaScript object; yes you can parse it in JS. Though as you have remote server as data publisher, you have to configure that server for a callback function. 
 To make the remote request, you insert a new script tag into your page, which will allow you to specify a remote URL. The reponse back will load a JSON object as a parameter of the callback function you specified in the request.

Once read somewhere. Hope it helped.